# Extract file from remote ssh host

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar

I have server2 with an file "/home/test.tar.gz".
On server1 i want to execute command via ssh to extract test.tar.gz to local directory.

Something like:

```
 sshpass -p 'password' ssh root@server2 "tar zxf /home/test.tar.gz" > /home/try
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Use scp & local tar, or remote tar & scp -r. Or sshfs/nfs to mount remote.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot redirect them to a  single file as you are extracting multiple types of files.

In case you are trying to extract to a directory then.

```
cd /tmp/try
ssh server2 "cat /home/test.tar.gz" | tar xvzf -
```

Comment: this is really interesting :D

Answer (score 0):

1st you should run ssh-copy-id or manually copy your ssh public key and share your server1 key to server2 and setup access without password.

follow below site :

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

then use below command to unzip file using ssh

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/user.pem user@server2 'tar -xzvf /home/user/test.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should:
- use ssh-copy-id to exchange key between first and second server in order to avoid the need to pass password.

Than you can:
- use SCP to copy the tar from server 2 and extract it with tar
Or
- extract the tar on the second machine in a directory and than copy that directory with scp -R